# how to get output of a script/program into a file?

Tags: gnome-terminal, output, redirect

I am compiling a program using make and want the output of make to be written to a file. I have tried using > operator like

```
make > build_log.txt
```

and using tee command like

```
make | tee build_log.txt
```

but the problem is that some of the ouput goes into the file but rest keeps appearing on the screen.

I can simply copy/paste the text from terminal into a file after running make but that is not a solution.

So my question is how do I save i.e redirect **all** the output to file so that it goes into file only without appearing on screen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The text that is displayed in the terminal comes from the `stderr` stream (2). If you do just `make > build_log.txt`, only the `stdout` (1) stream is redirected to the `build_log.txt` file.

- `stdout` is the standard output stream and has file descriptor number 1. This is the default stream being redirected in shells.
- `stderr` is the standard error stream and has file descriptor number 2

To redirect the `stderr` stream to that `build_log.txt` file too, use:

```
make > build_log.txt 2>&1
```

- `make` is executed and

  - the `stdout` stream is redirected (`>`) to `build_log.txt`
  - the `stderr` stream is redirected (`2>`) to the `stdout` stream (`&1`), which was redirected to `build_log.txt`

The order is important, you cannot switch switch the redirection operators like `make 2>&1 > build_log.txt`.

Alternative command:

```
make 2>&1 | tee build_log.txt > /dev/null
```

The redirection to `/dev/null` is needed to hide output, `tee` writes its input to `build_log.txt` and outputs it too.

Comment: can you plz explain '2>&1'. is 2 on commandline always going to mean error stream? and why is & used with 2 but not 1.

Comment: @binW: I've updated it, is it more clear now?

Comment: only a small thing is unclear :( why use &1. If stdout is 1 then shouldnt 2>1 do the job instead of 2>&1. when is & used with stream number?

Comment: `2>1` would redirect the standard error stream to a file named `1`, where `2>&1` redirects to the standard output stream. `&` makes the distinction between a file name and a file descriptor number.